# Define new variable for each index of an array

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am creating a grade logging iOS app that takes a users input of a grade and stores that grade into an array. Then on a separate view all of the grades are spit out into a cell table. I would like to create a new cell each time that the user inputs a new grade, rather than currently having the cells appear as hardcoded specific cells.

I was thinking some sort of for loop could be created... but I don't know how to do so.

```
struct MyVariables {
    static var physicsExamGradesArray = [Double]()
    static var GradeArray = [Double]()
    static let classesOption = ["Choose Class", "Physics", "Math"]
    static let assignmentOption = ["Choose Type","Exam", "Quiz", "Homework"]
    static var physicsGradesArray = [Double]()
}

import UIKit

class GradeLogViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var gradesCellsToBeDisplayed: [GradeProperties] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gradesCellsToBeDisplayed = createArray()

    }

}

func createArray() -> [GradeProperties] {

    var grades: [GradeProperties] = []

    let grade1 = GradeProperties(assignmentClass: "Physics", assignmentType: "Exam", assignmentIndex: 1, assignmentGrade: MyVariables.physicsExamGradeArray[0])
    let grade2 = GradeProperties(assignmentClass: "Physics", assignmentType: "Exam", assignmentIndex: 2, assignmentGrade: MyVariables.physicsExamGradeArray[1])

    grades.append(grade1)
    grades.append(grade2)

    return grades
}

extension GradeLogViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return gradesCellsToBeDisplayed.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let displayedGrade = gradesCellsToBeDisplayed[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhysicsCell") as! PhysicsCell

        cell.setContents(grade: displayedGrade)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Right now I have two grade cells hardcoded... but I would like for the cells to auto generate based on the number of grades that are inputted...

--EDIT--

The user inputs their grades through a UITextField, and the values are passed into variables shown under `struct MyVariables`.

Comment: You want to append to your `gradesCellsToBeDisplayed` array but it is unclear how the input of grades works.

Comment: How you are taking input from the user? There only your `physicsExamGradesArray` will be populated dynamically, right now you are creating it in your code.

Comment: The user inputs their values into text fields which then pass the values into static variables in the `MyVariables struct` @AnkitJayaswal @Joakim